# XSLT: setting an attribute of a previous node

Tags: xslt

Given the following sample;

```
<ul id="s-nav">
  <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::node [@level=2]/node">
    <li>
      <xsl:if test="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::node/@id = current()/@id">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">current</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
    </li>
  </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

When the current node is the same as the current <li>, the attribute class is set to 'current'.

Now I want to set a second attribute within the if block, but for the previous <li>, not the current. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you want to attach class="previous"? If so does this apply to just the `li` before the one that matches current, or to all `li` that come before the one that matches current? When asking about XSLT it is often helpful to provide both the XSLT and some sample XML to help people visualize the structure.

Comment: You're right. The class applies just to the one before the match.

Comment: How is currentPage defined? What does your XML look like? Which XSLT engine are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that XSLT will let you modify the attributes of nodes that have already been output. The best thing is to think about each node as its output, and work out the conditions under which it should have various attributes.